# Opposite of reluctance?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a suitable antonym of "reluctance" or "hesitance" **that does not have** the connotation of "rash judgment/action" or any negative connotation? Instead, I am looking for an antonym that suggests that someone **is not afraid to deal with the problem at hand.**

Comment: Please give us a sample sentence with a blank where the word should go. That way we can see from the context what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

***[Readiness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/readiness)***

> Willingness to do something.
>
> <sub>OED</sub>

Answer (score 3):

- Eagerness
  (strongly desiring)
  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Eagerness
- Willingness
  (not reluctant, but not quite eager either)
  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/willingness

Answer (score 3):

**enthusiasm** (*noun*):

a feeling of energetic interest in a particular subject or activity, and a willingness to be involved in it

> '*One of the good things about teaching young children is their enthusiasm.*'

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be 'willingness'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work: [embracement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/embracement).